# Как спользовать библиотку для кропа картинок CanHub / Android-Image-Cropper?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я хочу использовать у себя в проэкте библиотеку для замены аватара в профиле: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Но я не пойму как её использовать(

Там указано для запуска нужно написать:

```
cropImage.launch(
      options {
        setGuidelines(Guidelines.ON)
      }
    )
```

Но что это за синтаксис такой?? Что это за options?? Может кто знает, подскажите плиз. Буду Благодарен.

Comment: Со строки 89: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/main/sample/src/main/kotlin/com/canhub/cropper/sample/SampleCropFragment.kt

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Большое спасибо!